# how do I set Time.zone = GMT+05:30

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2. I want to set the time zone to GMT+05:30. But the following command gives me an error:

```
Time.zone = GMT+05:30

SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

Comment: first of all - you won't have access to rails components in standart irb console, you have to launch rails console

Comment: This I tested on rails console. ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to turn a string like that into a TimeZone you'll first have to convert it into an offset which you can do with a little regex.

```
time_zone_string = "GMT+5:30"
offset = time_zone_string.match(/GMT(\+|-)(\d+):(\d+)/) { "#{$1}1".to_i * ($2.to_i.hours + $3.to_i.minutes) }
time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(offset)
time_zone # (GMT+5:30) Chennai
```

Answer (score 3):

get the name of the timezone and not the offset.

```
>> Time.zone = 'New Delhi'
>> Time.now # Mon, 25 Feb 2013 18:04:43 IST +05:30
```

Comment: You are right but I get GMT+05:30 from a javascript code so I get problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the offset you can just do

```
Time.zone = 19600
```

You can also use some of the rails helpers

```
Time.zone = 5.hours + 30.minutes
```

I'm not sure what this will do with regards to daylight savings